# Stuck with send hash with remote true

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was stuck at a point badly..when I was doing with Rails form_for submit request with remote:true with a hidden field containing array of hashes as below:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :staff_stat_data, :value =>[{a: "a"} , {b: "b"}] %>
```

then I am getting hash as a string in parameter like:

```
"{:a=>\"a\"} {:b=>\"b\"}"
```

Badly stuck with this.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I have some data in array of hash in html form and i need to send this back to controller with remote: true..While Submitted the modal form the data in params is going as string instead of array of hashes.

[{a: "a"} , {b: "b"}]  => changing in to  "{:a=>\"a\"} {:b=>\"b\"}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting a hash, you're getting a string that kind of looks like a hash.

Remember that each parameter is just a string, that's how data is passed between clients and servers. Rails can sometimes receive an array, but only when the parameter names describe an array (e.g, `"user_favourites[]"`).

If you want to pass a single string that represents an array or hash, you can use JSON to encode/parse the data.

In your view, first change the array to its JSON representation like this:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :staff_stat_data, :value => [{a: "a"} , {b: "b"}].to_json %>
```

Then in your controller, change it to a hash by parsing the JSON like this:

```
staff_stat_data = JSON.parse(params[:staff_stat_data])
```

This will return you an array, where each element is a hash, just like you want.

You can try this out easily in your Rails console.

```
json = [{a: "a"} , {b: "b"}].to_json # => "[{\"a\":\"a\"},{\"b\":\"b\"}]"
JSON.parse(json) # => [{a: "a"} , {b: "b"}]
```

Comment: Remember to mark this as the answer to your question.